# undefined method `comments_count' for Article in Ruby on Rails guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am new to Rails. I followed the [Getting Started Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) of Rails 5.1.4 to put up a blog. My `articles/index.html.erb` template file reads like this:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <%= article.comments.count %></td>
<% end %>
```

Everything works great.

---

However, in the next guide under the [Schema Conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions) section, we are introduced to a reserved column name called `(table_name)_count`. It says we can use `comments_count` as a column name on the article model to get cached count of the comments associated with that article.

So I re-write my `articles/index.html.erb` template like this:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <%= article.comments_count %></td>
<% end %>
```

But when i reload the browser, i get the following error:

> undefined method `comments_count' for #Article:0x007fb51fb001b8. Did
>   you mean?  comments

What am i missing?

Comment: `comments_count` may be a "reserved name" (i.e. with special behaviour), but you still need to **add that column to your database schema**!! It's not *completely* magic.

Comment: See section 4.1.2.3 of [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: Hmm. But this column name is listed in the guide _along with_ other columns which _are_ magically available - like `created_at`, `updated_at` etc.

Comment: "Magically available" as in, they get created as part of default migrations... Each database migration you wrote that creates a table presumably contains the line: `t.timestamps`. This *tells* rails to create those columns as part of the migration. If you didn't write `t.timestamps` in the migration file, then those columns wouldn't exist either. And if you look at your `db/schema.rb` (or even just connect to the database directly!), you'll see those columns exist.

Comment: The `<table_name>_count` columns, on the other hand, are not created by default - as it would be incredibly wasteful and inefficient to generate counters for *all* associations, *everywhere*. You should only create them (manually) when needed, for performance.

Comment: Thanks @TomLord . Can you kindly write these as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the [rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions) is saying here is that there are certain *default behavioural conventions* applied to columns with certain names/patterns (which can also be altered/removed, if desired).

For example, the `created_at` column (*if it exists!*) will **automatically** be set when you create the record. Or, the `type` column (again, *if it exists!*) will automatically (unless you tell it not to) be interpreted for use in the context of [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance).

When you generate a rails model to create a new table (`rails generate model person`), the default migration file contains the line `t.timestamps`. This is optional, but it tells Rails to include the columns: `created_at` and `updated_at` for your table.

However, other columns such as `comments_count` will *not* be created "by default" (as it would be highly inefficient to have counter caches for *every* association!). In order to use this functionality, you need to explicitly create the columns in a new migration file.

You can see the structure of your database (including the presence of `created_at`/`updated_at` columns, but absence of a `comments_count` column) by reading `db/schema.rb` (or just connecting to the database directly, of course!)

See the [rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache) for more information on how to implement a counter cache.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is when you add the special column the call to `comments.size` actually uses that column instead of counting the columns. You don't have to change your code.

Take look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache